# Eigenvalues using cholesky factors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

When a matrix $A_0$, for example $2 \times 2$ matrix, is symmetric positive definite, the following steps can compute the eigenvalues of $A_0$,

$A_k=R^T_k R_k$ (Cholesky Decomposition)

$A_{k+1}=R_k R^T_k$

where $k$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$ i.e., $A_1$ is calculated using cholesky factor of $A_0$, $A_2$ is calculated using cholesky factor of $A_1$ and so on..

Finally,
\begin{equation} 
A_\infty=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1&0\\
0&\lambda_2 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are eigenvalues of $A_0$.Why this procedure can reach the eigenvalues of $A_0$?

Comment: I don't get your indices, what is $A_{k+2}$ with your notations?

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Observe that $R_k^T=A_kR_k^{-1}$, so $A_{k+1}=R_kA_kR_k^{-1}$, hence $A_{k+1}$ and $A_k$ have the same eigenvalues. Now it remains to show that $A_k$ tends to a diagonal matrix, which is probably not as easy. // Related, though not identical: [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm)

Comment: Have found something that might help you: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T-Dtl9XhPi3IyBueRm5d4YHZPj60BswQ/view?usp=sharing would love to hear a simple explanation :-)

Comment: @Jeanba: "Your session has timed out. Please go back to the article page and click the PDF link again." Please link to the article page and not directly to the PDF.

Comment: Sorry you experienced the problem, I edited the link as soon as I became aware of it but apparently you were too fast :-)

Comment: -I have figured out that this is similar to the problem of LR decomposition. Thank you for your help. However, the question has one more condition. For the matrix $A_0$, the upper left element $a_{11}$ is given to be greater than the lower right element $a_{22}$. I don't know why that is important for the question.

Comment: I think it may possibly have to do with the permutation matrice P (as defined for instance in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072534/permutation-matrix-and-lu-decomposition). Having some pre-condition on the matrix may prevent having to perform some column swapping during the Gaussian elimination process so that P is the Identity matrix. (This is just an idea, this might not be the core reason)